# How can I plot multiple labels at specified locations in GraphicsGrid?

Tags: output-formatting

I used `Show` to combine two plots A and B so that I have `plot1`. The same for plots C and D so that I have `plot2`.  Then I used the following code:

```
Graphicdgrid[
  {{plot1}, {plot2}},
  PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["title  here"], 12, Black, Bold,
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, None},None, "text here"}}
```

I am trying two things: place a text on right side of the graph to explain the picture; place a legend for two plots, each of which show two unique curves.  How do I place multiple labels at custom location in a graphics grid. The above `FrameLabel` option does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have syntax errors. Secondly, instead of FrameLabel and PlotLabel, Epilog is better. Here is an example:

```
p11 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}];
p12 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -3, 3}];
p21 = Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, -3, 3}];
p22 = Plot[Cos[2 x], {x, -3, 3}];

plot1 = Show[p11, p12];
plot2 = Show[p21, p22];

GraphicsGrid[{{plot1}, {plot2}}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[Style["Sine", 20], Scaled[{0.75, 0.75}]], 
   Inset[Style["AnyText", 20], Scaled[{0.5, 0}]]}]
```

Note that you get full flexibility in positioning your labels in a scaled {0,1} co-ordinate system.